# AngularJS page reloading before $state.go

Tags: angularjs

I'm following [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) .. First time I execute function (fazerLogin) from ng-click, after set cookies, I don't know why, it is reloading current state before $state.go function. When button activates fazerLogin function(first time only), it executes all the code, but before my `$state.go('temperatura')`, it "reloads" the same state, executing my function `initController()` and cleaning all credentials. If I try to login again, it works perfectly. And if I'm logged and I go to state login again, it works, without any of this problem. There is my code

LoginController:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($timeout, $rootScope, $location, $scope, $cookies, $state, AuthService){
    (function initController() {
    AuthService.LimparCredenciais();
    })();

    $scope.fazerLogin = function () {
      if(angular.isUndefined($scope.login)){
        swal("Preencha o campo 'Login'");
        $('#usuario').focus();
      }else if(angular.isUndefined($scope.senha)){
        swal("Preencha o campo 'Senha'");
        $('#senha').focus();
      }else{
        $scope.usuario = {login: $scope.login, senha: $scope.senha};
        AuthService.Login($scope.usuario, function(response) {
            if(response != null) {
                if(!response.status){
                  swal("Login ou senha incorretos!");
                }else{
                  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM THAT IS RELOADING CURRENT PAGE
                  AuthService.AtualizarCredenciais(response.usuario);
                  $state.go('temperatura');
                }
            } else {
                swal("ERRO");
            }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

And my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ui.router', 'ui.materialize', 'ngResource', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ngCookies', 'zingchart-angularjs']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {


// $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "pages/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
});

app.run(function($cookies, $rootScope, $location, $state, $cookies, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.baseUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    $rootScope.global = $cookies.get('global') || {};
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        // redirect to login page if not logged in
        if ($location.path() !== '/login' && angular.isUndefined($rootScope.global.usuario)
                && $location.path() !== '/cadastro') {
                    $state.go('login');
        }
    });

});
```

In my AuthService, there is my code:

```
angular.module("app").factory(
        "AuthService",
        function(Base64, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $timeout, Usuario, $state) {
            var service = {}

            service.Login = function(usuario, callback) {
                 Usuario.logar(usuario)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        callback(data);
                    }).error(function(erro) {
                        // $state.go('erro');
                    });
            };

            service.AtualizarCredenciais = function(usuario) {
                console.log("atualizando credenciais");
                var key = Base64.encode(usuario.login + ':' + usuario.senha);
                $rootScope.global = {
                    usuario : {
                        login : usuario.login,
                        key : key,
                        id : usuario.id
                    }
                };
                $cookies.put('global', $rootScope.global);
                console.log('setou cookies');
                //AFTER SET COOKIES, IT IS RELOADING CURRENT STATE AND EXECUTING METHOD TO CLEAR CURRENT CREDENTIALS
            };    

            service.LimparCredenciais = function() {
                console.log("limpando credenciais");
                $rootScope.global = {};
                $cookies.remove('global');
            };
            return service;
        });
```

In my login.html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <a ng-click="fazerLogin()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12">Login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my Usuario.js, there are only posts to my php files to get some data from database.

Comment: Can you add your HTML where ng-click is declared

Comment: @UmerZ of course. I edited my question!